# Execute a class function indicated by argument upon class initialisation in Python

Tags: python, class, initialization, self

I'm looking to create functions within a class which, when run, change the self values of the class.  I'd also like to be able to run these functions when initialising the class, hopefully by passing them as arguments.

As a specific example, let's say i have class `foo`, with self value `thing` and function `bar`.  Upon initialising `foo`, i want to pass `bar` as an argument, which will then run the function `bar` and change `thing` accordingly.  So:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, function_to_call):
        self.thing = ""
        self.function_to_call()

    def bar(self):
        self.thing = "blah blah blah"

myClassInstance = Foo(bar)
print(myClassInstance.thing)
```

So, in this case, i'd like the latter line to return "blah blah blah."  Is this possible?  If so, how?  Currently i'm being told that `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'function_to_call'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in a reference to the unbound class method:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, function_to_call):
        self.thing = ""
        function_to_call(self)

    def bar(self):
        self.thing = "blah blah blah"

myClassInstance = Foo(Foo.bar)
print(myClassInstance.thing)
```

Result:

```
blah blah blah
```

---

Aside: it's not clear to me why you would want to do this, when it's much more straightforward to call `bar` the line after you create the Foo. Then you don't need to do any function-passing at all.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing = ""

    def bar(self):
        self.thing = "blah blah blah"

myClassInstance = Foo()
myClassInstance.bar()
print(myClassInstance.thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to pass the method name as a string. You can then use `getattr` to fetch the bound method.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, funcname):
        self.thing = ""
        getattr(self, funcname)()

    def bar(self):
        self.thing = "blah blah blah"

foo = Foo('bar')
print(foo.thing)
```

**output**

```
blah blah blah
```